# how to create a row in sum set for group in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have table **Tab** (`id,, DeptName, Total, ...`)

There are 4 possible values for `Deptname`: `Dept1, Dept2, Dept3, Dept4`.

Then I can issue SQL for grouping like this:

```
Select DeptName, Totaol = Sum(total) 
from Tab 
group by DeptName
```

Normally, the result is will have 4 rows based on the value of `DeptName`:

```
DeptName Total
Dept1    1234.09
Dept2    234.80
Dept3    34.34
Dept4    614.48
```

If there is no data for `Dept2`, the result will only has 3 rows:

```
Dept1    1234.09
Dept3    34.34
Dept4    614.48
```

What I want is the result always has 4 rows. If there is no data for `Dept2`, I want the result like:

```
Dept1    1234.09
Dept2    0
Dept3    34.34
Dept4    614.48
```

How to implement this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems right [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52158/11/0):

```
SELECT t2.DeptName, Total = COALESCE(Sum(total),0)
FROM Tab t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 'Dept1' as DeptName UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Dept2' UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Dept3' UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Dept4') t2 ON t2.DeptName = t1.DeptName
GROUP BY t2.DeptName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select b.DeptName,b.Total from(
select 'Dept1' as Dept union all
select 'Dept2' as Dept union all
select 'Dept3' as Dept union all
select 'Dept4' as Dept )a left outer join
(
Select DeptName, case when b.DeptName IS null then 0 else SUM(total) end as Total
from Tab 
group by DeptName)b
on b.DeptName=a.Dept
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "union all" to break each row into multiple rows:

```
select dept, sum(val) as sumval
from ((select 'dept1' as dept, t.dept1 as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept2', t.dept2 as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept3', t.dept3 as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept4', t.dept4 as val from tab t)
     ) t
group by dept
order by 1
```

If you have lots and lots of data, the following might be a bit more efficient:

```
      (select 'dept1' as dept, sum(t.dept1) as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept2', sum(t.dept2) as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept3', sum(t.dept3) as val from tab t) union all
      (select 'dept4', sum(t.dept4) as val from tab t)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am worry about performance for this case with too many union all.